# Showing a fake outgoing dialing number

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I want to show a fake outgoing dialing number.

Suppose I dial a number 987654321. Although internally this number would get dialed and call would go through.

But, on the phone screen the dialing number would show something like 5329253223.

I scanned the internet but not able to find a relevant answer.

Apologies if my question is difficult to understand.

Yash

Comment: You can't do this. You can only make app look like dialing screen.

Comment: I am not perfectly sure but if you can store this number 987654321 with 5329253223 before calling will trick user but its just lazy workaround as some devices shows the original number along with contact name, else looking forward to know how one can achieve it.

Comment: @EliaszKubala I have successfully made my app replace the dialing screen (including hiding the notification bar)....but I am not able to find a way to make notification bar inaccessible.....when a user pulls down the notification bar..he can see the number being dialed...thats why trying out this approach...

Comment: @RamIndani Thanks for the trick...I ll try this approach...at least it will work out on some of the devices

Comment: @user3055413 please update if you find solution or this trick works for you.